# How to iterate through an array with objects and array of objects in multiple levels?

Tags: arrays, swift, logic

I have an array which contains objects. These objects may have other arrays of objects, then those objects also may have other objects and array of objects. There is no limit really.

So how do I go through all the objects in this array no matter how deeply nested they are? If I know how deep the arrays go, I can easily do this by using a number of for loops. I having problem with going through all the elements.

I am not able to come up with a logic to do that. Can somebody please help me? I am trying to do this in swift.

Comment: If you don't know how deep your array can be, you are in real trouble. You need to rethink your design. And if you don't help yourself, no one will be able to help you here. When you make an effort, you can share your code here to get better response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Have an `Any` object.
- Store the values into that object how you need it.
- When you read the object, cast it to the required array.
- If the casting is successfull, then you can access that `Any` object like an array.

Comment: But how do I go through each elements without knowing how deep it is? I mean if it was 2 levels deep I could have put 3 for loops. But in this case I don't have any idea. I know how to access the items without issue. Sorry if I was no clear. Updating the question now.

Comment: Use recursion. Have a method to which you pass this `Any` object. If casting to an array is successful, call that method individually to every element of that array.